# Frisch Waugh theorem for removing fixed effect

Tags: regression, cross-validation

My data have three levels: industry, firm, and year.

I would like to find how much firm variation of sales is explained by age. I want to use the Frisch Waugh theorem. I follow the following steps:

1. I regress sales on industry and year dummies and get the sales residual.
2. I regress age on industry and year dummies and get the age residual.
3. Then I regress the sales residual on the age residual without constant.
4. and find the R square, which is the firm variation of sales explained by age.

I follow similar steps to find the year variation of sales explained by age.

Am I correct? Or better to find those variations.

Comment: Welcome to CV. How have you been able to define firm age? How and why is sales or top line revenue a good target variable? Particularly since, for long time series, it is associated with inflation. Not to mention that many studies have been and are being published on the decreasing life span, e.g., of companies comprising the S&P 500.

Comment: @DJohnson : Thanks. I have data for firm age. Actually, I would like to know whether sales or revenue varies with firm age and how much.

Comment: So, you have fixed N and t? Why not treat it as a panel data model as described by Wooldridge in his book *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*?

Comment: @DJohnson I would like to get R square. Panel model includes both age effect and fixed effect. This will give you a higher R square.

Comment: Towards what objective? Relative importance of age in predicting sales? There are many papers criticizing R-square as a less than meaningful measure of importance.

Comment: I know this. Still I would like to estimate this.

Comment: Your choice. For a really thorough discussion of a wide range of variable relative importance methods see the papers by Ulrike Groemping. In particular, she has an easily run R module called RELAIMPO that is one of the more sophisticated approaches.